# Swift class get set

Tags: swift

My code is below:

```
class myClass{
    var left = 1.3;
    var right = 1.4;
    var both:Double{
        get{
            return ((left+right)/2)
        }
        set(neweyes){
            left = neweyes - 0.1
            right = neweyes + 0.1
        }
    }
}
let myCl = myClass()
myCl.both
myCl.neweyes = 1.5
```

error is show:

> Col 6: expression resolves to an unused l-value
>   Col 1: value of type 'myClass' has no member 'neweyes'
>   how to fix this

Comment: `myCl.both = 1.5`

Comment: the argument `neweyes` in your setter is only known within the setter.  If you want to change the value of `both`, you just have to call

`myCL.both = 1.5`

Answer (score 0):

```
class myClass{
var left = 1.3;
var right = 1.4;
var both:Double {
    get{
        return ((left+right)/2)
    }
    set(neweyes){
        left = neweyes - 0.1
        right = neweyes + 0.1
    }
}
}


let myCl = myClass() // left = 1.3 right = 1.4
myCl.both            // 1.3500000000000001
myCl.both = 10.0     //left 9.9 right 10.1
myCl.both            // 10
```